# SQL - Determine what user ran query when Active Directory Group authentication is used

Tags: sql-server-2008, active-directory

Currently using Active Directory Groups to authenticate users.  What I want to know is if group A has 100 users.  How can I tell what users are specifically logged in at the current time.  It's my understanding the SQL will display the group information not the exact user.

Answer (score 0):

The T-SQL function SUSER_SNAME() will return the **domain\login** of the user connected to SQL Server. But that is the extent of the "user information" you can get out-of-the-box.

**EDIT:** You can use `exec sp_who2` which returns a result set with **domain\user**.

Comment: but does it return domain\<ad_group> or domain\<user>?

Comment: So if my AD login is domain\MyGuy and my SQLServer Login is domain\MyGroups running SUSER_SNAME() returns domain\MyGuy

Comment: HardCode- that returns when that user runs the query, how do I see the other users....like if i ran it for all users in a DB

Comment: Yes. Just try it and you'll see. Create a stored procedure to write SUSER_SNAME() into a table as a test.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I completely missed the point that you want to see the users currently connected. I'll edit my original answer.

Comment: EXEC sp_who will show whos logged in but does it translate AD group logins?